# Matching value in Map for using in Mockito.when

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, argument-matcher

Dears, I'm trying to using  Mockito to create different mocks based on a value contained in a Map.
Following the documentation I created two different ArgumentMatchers that run the logic

```
private class ConsumerValidMap implements ArgumentMatcher<Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Map<String, Object> argument) {
        return argument.get("TYPE").equals("CONSUMER");
    }
}

private class BayValidMap implements ArgumentMatcher<Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Map<String, Object> argument) {
        return argument.get("TYPE").equals("BAY");
    }
}
```

If I create the Mock as following:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Mockito.when(idAndTypeDtoMapper.toDto(argThat(new ConsumerValidMap()))).thenReturn(identityConsumer);
    Mockito.when(idAndTypeDtoMapper.toDto(argThat(new BayValidMap()))).thenReturn(identityBay); 
}
```

I got the errors:

```
[MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at com.virtualentity.unit.service.ExtractorServiceTest.setUp(ExtractorServiceTest.java:123)
[MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at com.virtualentity.unit.service.ExtractorServiceTest.setUp(ExtractorServiceTest.java:124)
```

Also I tried to create the istances of the ArgumentMatchers but still I got the errors. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: can you add the complete test class or at least the setup method ?  and which version java you are using ?

Comment: i'm using junit4 and java 11